# Open and close image in default image viewer

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to create a short method that opens an image in the default image viewer, and after `time` milliseconds closes it.

Right now it looks like this:

```
    public static async void OpenImage(string path, int time)
    {
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        process.Start();
        await Task.Delay(time);
        process.Kill()
        process.Close()
    }
```

I can see the image, but then `process.Kill()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`, "No process is associated with this object."

Have I missed something or is there any other way to do it?

---

**Update:**

Also tested this now:

```
    public static async void OpenImage(string path, int time)
    {
        var process = Process.Start(path)
        await Task.Delay(time);
        process.Kill()
        process.Close()
    }
```

But then `Process.Start()` returns `null`. So maybe I have to call on the `.exe` directly like faljbour commented?

Comment: I think your process terminated before you called kill on it, if you remove the kill() and close(), your exception might go away

Comment: But then it will never close? I can still see that the image viewer is open so it's not that it close before I call on kill(). That's why I'm a bit confused by the exception.

Comment: would you post the code the calls this OpenImage method, I would like to see what is in path.

Comment: It's a bit long to post, but the path is just a normal path to an image on my computer, for example "C:\SomeFolder\image.png"

Comment: but what executable are you trying to kill.  You must be using an executable to show the image

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have to set anything. It use the default viewer by the file type as I understand it. You find more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808029/open-image-in-windows-photo-viewer

Comment: I would call the method WaitForExit() and see if it returns before you call process.kill, you can set it to wait for few seconds

Comment: I just thought about this topic.  The process.kill() is trying to kill the windows process that invoked the image viewer, that process invoked the viewer and terminated.  To control the start and termination of the image viewer, I would recommend to call the exe of the image viewer.  Let me know if you would like an example of how to invoke a viewer and have the image as  a command line arugment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not really starting a process, but rather passing a file path to the Windows Shell (`explorer.exe`) to handle. The shell figures out how to open the file and *it* starts the process.

When this happens your code doesn't get the process id back, so it doesn't know which process to kill.

What you should do, is find the default application for the file and then start that application explicitly (rather than letting the shell figure it out).

The most compact way I can think of to find the default application for a file is to use the Win32 API [`FindExecutable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540278/4593760).

---

Things are complicated a little when the default application is contained within a dll. This is the case with the default Windows photo viewer (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll`). Since it is not a `exe` you cannot start it directly, however the application can be started using [`rundll32`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787).

---

This should work for you:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int FindExecutable(string lpFile, string lpDirectory, [Out] StringBuilder lpResult);

public static async void OpenImage(string imagePath, int time)
{
    var exePathReturnValue = new StringBuilder();
    FindExecutable(Path.GetFileName(imagePath), Path.GetDirectoryName(imagePath), exePathReturnValue);
    var exePath = exePathReturnValue.ToString();
    var arguments = "\"" + imagePath + "\"";

    // Handle cases where the default application is photoviewer.dll.
    if (Path.GetFileName(exePath).Equals("photoviewer.dll", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        arguments = "\"" + exePath + "\", ImageView_Fullscreen " + imagePath;
        exePath = "rundll32";
    }

    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    process.Start();

    await Task.Delay(time);

    process.Kill();
    process.Close();
}
```

---

This code demonstrates the concept, but if you want to cater for more default applications with unusual argument formats (as shown by `photoviewer.dll`), you should search the [registry yourself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148.aspx) or use a third party library to find the correct command line to use.

For example,

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17023/System-File-Association

Comment: When I try this, I get a System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.', because exePath is empty