# C# Opening Images with default viewer - Not possible to navigate through more images

Tags: c#, .net, image, .net-core, process

When I try to open an image with the default picture viewer, it only loads the targeted image. Thats a problem, because its not possible to navigate/browse through the other images in the directory.

This is how I open the image:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", ImagePathString);
```

Maybe I need to start it directly with default viewer without the explorer handling it. But I don't how to parse it. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677997/12273101), but it didn't work.
I get a System.InvalidOperationException, because it cant find the right executable.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot start process because a file
> name has not been provided.'

Is there a way to load all Images from a directory or just enable the functions to navigate forwards and backwards?

Answer (score 1):

You must give the `executable file of picture viewer` as a `FileName` parameter to the process:

```
Process photoViewer = new Process();

//executable file of picture viewer
photoViewer.StartInfo.FileName = @"F:\Google.Picasa\Picasa3\Picasa3.exe";
photoViewer.StartInfo.Arguments =ImagePathString;
photoViewer.Start();
```

Comment: This helps a bit. Sadly you can't just target to the windows Photo viewer or other apps downloaded from the MS.
It does work with Picasa